# Mocking System.Collections.Generic.IList with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am struggeling with writing unit tests for my class AttachmentProcessor.
My goal is to test all methods and mock for example IList FileList.

```
    public class AttachmentsProcessor
    {
      public IList<IFileInfo> FileList { get; set; }

    public AttachmentsProcessor(IList<IFileInfo> FileList)
    {
       ...
    }

    public void RemoveAttachment(int index)
    {
     ...
    }

    public long GetTotalFilesSize()
    {
     ...
    }

    public void GetFilesFromDialog(IOpenFileDialog2 openFileDialog1)
    {
     ...
    }   
}
```

Interface :

```
public interface IFileProcessor
{
    IList<IFileInfo> FileList { get; set; }

    void RemoveAttachment(int index);

    long GetTotalFilesSize();

    void GetFilesFromDialog(IOpenFileDialog2 openFileDialog1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you unit testing that in the first place? You're just wrapping a list for convience methods, you don't even need that method in the first place,  Secondly AttachmentsInfo may be a IFileInfo, but not vice versa so if you want to act upon it like so your initial call must be AttachmentsProcessor<IFileInfo> but if you're going to do that you should use a structure better suited to handle co-variance and contravariance

Comment: Quick question - what is benefit of using `AttachmentProcessor` over using simple `List<AttahcmentsInfo>`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have methods like
GetSizeOfAllAttachments, GetFilesFromDialog,  or GetFilesFromDragandDrop Event etc.

Comment: @johnny5 thank you for your reply ...it makes sense. But I still don't know how to mock a List<AttachmentInfo>. I just want to moq the AttachmentInfo objects in that list.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Post a function you're trying to moq.  You are aware that you don't have to moq everything sometimes you just need to make. Fake dto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. My problem was that I did not know how to make mocks for my *Class AttachmentProcessor:IFileProcessor and List*.
I ended up with this solution and it worked ! Thanks for all replies.

```
        var mockFileProcessor = new Mock<IFileProcessor>(); //here is how I mocked my AttachmentProcessor
        var mockAttachmentInfo = new Mock<IFileInfo>(); ///here is how I mocked my AttachmentInfo
        mockAttachmentInfo.Setup(m => m.Length).Returns(() => 200);
        mockFileProcessor.Setup(m => m.FileList).Returns(() => new List<IFileInfo> 
        {
         mockAttachmentInfo.Object,
         mockAttachmentInfo.Object,
         mockAttachmentInfo.Object, 
         mockAttachmentInfo.Object,
         mockAttachmentInfo.Object 
        }); /// and this is the part where I mocked my IList<AttachmentInfo>
```

I ended up with this solution and it worked ! Thanks for all replies